# Dúvida na elaboração de uma query em SQL

Tags: mysql, union

Será que me podiam dizer o que está de errado neste código de SQL?
Quero que para cada filme, os salários de cada *staff* não apareçam repetidos, ou seja, se no primeiro filme tiver 2 *leads*, na tabela eu quero a soma desses valores para o *lead*.

```
select Ms.salary as Total_salaries, R.title as papeis, M.title as filmes
from Movies M, Staff St, MovieStaff Ms, Roles R
where Ms.mvid=M.mvid
and Ms.stid=St.stid
and Ms.rid=R.rid
union 
select Ma.salary as Total_salaries, Ar.title as papeis_atores, M.title as filmes
from Movies M, Staff St, MovieActors Ma, ActorRoles Ar, Actors A
where Ma.mvid=M.mvid
and Ma.aid=A.aid
and A.aid=St.stid
and Ma.arid=Ar.arid;
```

Para que nao aconteça isto:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso deve usar uma função de agregação `sum(coluna)` que soma os valores da coluna e o `group by` que agrupa os dados pelas colunas que são selecionadas exceto a que está fazendo o cálculo.

```
select sum(Ms.salary) as Total_salaries, R.title as papeis, M.title as filmes
from Movies M, Staff St, MovieStaff Ms, Roles R
where Ms.mvid=M.mvid
and Ms.stid=St.stid
and Ms.rid=R.rid
group by papeis, filmes
union 
select sum(Ma.salary) as Total_salaries, Ar.title as papeis_atores, M.title as filmes
from Movies M, Staff St, MovieActors Ma, ActorRoles Ar, Actors A
where Ma.mvid=M.mvid
and Ma.aid=A.aid
and A.aid=St.stid
and Ma.arid=Ar.arid
group by papeis, filmes;
```

Respondi tua pergunta, porém é bom estudar sobre o group by: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 0):

Você pode somar os salários, mas não da para agregar os filmes e os papeis.
Vc pode ver isso no link que o Laércio Lopes mandou...

Se precisar de algum código, mande o arquivo sql com as tabelas usadas no exemplo.